# Custom styles for minted in Overleaf

Tags: listings, minted, overleaf

So I just moved from `listings` to `minted`, as `listings` had super annoying problems with lines showing up when the background color is set to dark. Minted, on the other hand, is annoying as there doesn't seem to be an easy way to define my own styles, [except in python](https://pygments.org/docs/styles/#creating-own-styles), but how would I achieve this in Overleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I was wrong, it does seem to be possible. See [Alex Reinking's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663690/21344) for details.

If my answer is eventually unaccepted I will delete it. Sorry for giving the wrong info!

---

I'm afraid this is not possible in Overleaf. You can load a custom lexer from a `.py` file without installing it, but unfortunately there isn't a way to load a Pygments style from a local `.py` file, without installing it or registering it as a plugin at the system level—this is not possible on Overleaf's compile servers.

If you have a requirement to use a custom style with Pygments, you'll need to install your own TeX distribution to compile on your own system.

Comment: Aw man! Thanks 

Comment: Actually, it is possible! See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663690/42504)

Comment: @AlexReinking oh very cool, I had not considered that angle. I would delete my answer, but it's currently accepted so I cannot do that. If it's ok with you I will edit to add a pointer to yours. Hopefully the accepted answer is changed at some point by the OP and I can delete this then.

Comment: @PaulGessler sounds good to me

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you just have to be willing to (ab)use minted's internals a little bit. The way minted works is that it asks `pygmentize` to create a file full of TeX macros that determine the style. If that file already exists, it just loads it into a macro named `\minted@PYGdef@<style>` where `<style>` is the style you wanted to load. As an optimization, if that macro already exists, it skips running `pygmentize`!

So here's how you can plug your own style file into the `minted` system:

```
\makeatletter
\CatchFileDef{\minted@PYGdef@thesis}{thesis-style}{\catcode`@=11\catcode`\%=14\catcode``=12\endlinechar=-1}
\makeatother

\usemintedstyle{thesis}
```

This creates a style called `thesis` from a file in your project root directory called `thesis-style.tex` (rather than `.pygstyle`, so that cloud editing works). The catcode business is to make sure that characters in the pygstyle file are interpreted correctly. Probably only `@` is actually necessary, but I copied the catcode settings from `minted` to be safe.

As for authoring the `pygstyle` file to begin with, you can either try to edit an existing one (build once with a style that's close enough and tweak) or create your own style from scratch by doing everything in Python locally and then freezing the `pygstyle` file (higher overhead, imo).

Lastly, this was done on the latest version of Minted, and so you should use TexLive 2022 on Overleaf.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done. For example, I have a custom lexer for a language called Portugol, so I upload the lexer with the name `PortugolStudioLexer.py` (the name is arbitrary). Then, you can start the minted environment using

```
\begin{minted}{PortugolStudioLexer.py:PortugolStudioLexer -x}

\end{minted}
```

You can also create your own commands with `minted` interface:

```
\setminted[PortugolStudioLexer.py:PortugolStudioLexer -x]{linenos}
\newmint[portugol]{PortugolStudioLexer.py:PortugolStudioLexer -x}{}
\newminted[portugolcode]{PortugolStudioLexer.py:PortugolStudioLexer -x}{
    tabsize=2, obeytabs}
\newmintinline[portugolinline]{PortugolStudioLexer.py:PortugolStudioLexer -x}{}
\newmintedfile[portugolfile]{PortugolStudioLexer.py:PortugolStudioLexer -x}{tabsize=2, obeytabs}
\newcommand{\portugolitem}{\portugolfile[linenos = false, xleftmargin = 2em]}
```

So you get the command `\portugol`, `\portugolinline`, `\portugolcode` and the environment `portugolcode`.

Comment: @PaulGessler FYI, this new answer seems to have found a solution for Over´eaf.

Comment: It looks like this is a lexer only, not a style, unless I'm missing some context about the contents of PortugolStudioLexer.py.

Comment: Just realized I misunderstood the question while I was searching. Thought he was talking about a custom lexer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [Alex's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663690/67358), it is also possible to patch the pygmentize installation of Overleaf to find and compile your styles from a python source (so that you don't have to pre-compile them locally).

This script does the trick: https://gist.github.com/dn0sar/d67672d3793271a2985e4ec20f425174 (the script is also pasted below)

Just place the script in the project root, then modify the `LOCAL_STYLE_MAP` of the script to add the specification to import your style (wherever it is in your project).

Finally, add the following two lines on your latex preamble to use the patched pygmentize version:

```
\immediate\write18{bash ./pygmentize_patcher.sh}
\renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{./pygmentize}
```

Note that `pygmentize_patcher.sh` is the name of the script. Now you can use as style the key names that you specified in the `LOCAL_STYLE_MAP` and pygmentize will find and load your style.

---

If you are curious about how this works, [this](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/0411c43c9cb8b9c8e7e8a25109d45994e300986e/pygments/styles/__init__.py#L82) is how pygmentize finds and loads builtin styles.

Note how every import is forced to start with `pygments.styles.` . The patch replaces the python builtin `__import__` so that the prefix `pygments.styles.` is removed for styles specified in `LOCAL_STYLE_MAP`.

Since Overleaf currently does not allow to overwrite the installed python files the patched pygmentize is saved in the project root. `\renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{./pygmentize}` then replaces the calls from the default `pygmentize` to the patched one.

This is the bash script from the gist above:

```
## Tested with Pygments 2.11.0 and 2.13.0

## Add your own styles in the python map defined in the local_style_map variable
## The format specification is given in the comments inside the variable
local_style_map=$(cat <<EOF
LOCAL_STYLE_MAP = {
    ## this key is the alias name of your style, add more if you have more styles
    'customcc' : {
        ## file from where to import the custom style class
        ## this is relative to the project root
        ## e.g,. if you have your custom style in custom_style/c_styles.py
        ## you should have the import below
        
        "file_import": "custom_style.c_styles", 
        
        ## Class name defined in the "file_import" above
        
        "class_name":  "CustomC", 
    },
}
EOF
)

##### DO NOT MODIFY BELOW HERE

pygmentize_path=$(which pygmentize)

# Take shebang from the current pygmentize installation
shebang=$(head -n 1 $pygmentize_path)
if [[ "${shebang:0:2}" != '#!' ]]; then
    shebang=""
fi

preamble=$(cat <<EOF

import builtins
from pygments.styles import STYLE_MAP

for k in LOCAL_STYLE_MAP:
    STYLE_MAP[k] = LOCAL_STYLE_MAP[k]["file_import"] + '::' + LOCAL_STYLE_MAP[k]["class_name"]

default_import = builtins.__import__

def custom_import(name, *args):
    for k in LOCAL_STYLE_MAP:
        if name == 'pygments.styles.' + LOCAL_STYLE_MAP[k]["file_import"]:
            # print(f'Patching search path to find "{k}"')
            name = LOCAL_STYLE_MAP[k]["file_import"]
    return default_import(name, *args)

builtins.__import__ = custom_import

EOF
)

echo "$shebang" > pygmentize
echo "" >> pygmentize
echo "$local_style_map" >> pygmentize
echo "$preamble" >> pygmentize
echo "" >> pygmentize
cat $pygmentize_path >> pygmentize

chmod u+x pygmentize
```