# Rendering with text and code block

Tags: code, syntax-highlighting

How to get, in Latex, this kind of rendering with firstly a text and just after a block of code with a shaded grey background ? I would like to get the same font for code block.

[image: text and code background shaded in grey]

Comment: To typeset the block of code, you should have a look at the [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Comment: `listings` is indeed a possibility, however this screenshot looks more like the [minted](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows a fixed font for the code. Using package
[`ffcode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ffcode) might be one way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ffcode}

\begin{document}
\begin{ffcode}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{ffcode}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

With package [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) though
you can have several themes with colored characters. Note
that I have also customized a background color using the
[`xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package for the
`vim` theme as the characters weren't easily visible.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{myblack}{black!50!white}

\begin{document}
\section*{Minted styles with non-italic comments}
\subsection*{Light theme}
\subsubsection*{\texttt{perldoc}}
\usemintedstyle{perldoc}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{r}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{minted}
\subsubsection*{\texttt{rrt}}
\usemintedstyle{rrt}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{r}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{minted}
\subsubsection*{\texttt{pastie}}
\usemintedstyle{colorful}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{r}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{minted}
\subsubsection*{\texttt{colorful}}
\usemintedstyle{colorful}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{r}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{minted}
\subsubsection*{\texttt{vs}}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{r}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{minted}
\subsection*{Dark theme}
\subsubsection*{\texttt{vim}}
\usemintedstyle{vim}
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=myblack,linenos]{r}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{minted}
\subsubsection*{\texttt{monokai}}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black,linenos]{r}
set.seed(123)
## do grid
y <- rcoga(100000, c(2, 5, 7), c(3, 2, 4))
grid <- seq(0,15,length.out=100)
## calculate pdf and cdf
\end{minted}
```

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

---

**Note:** For using any of these packages; you need to
install `python3-pygments` package and invoke
`--shell-escape` flag in the terminal as follows.

```bash
pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! is it possible to have colorified code with ffcode ?

Comment: `ffcode` seems to be a strict package, but `minted` itself is quite flexible. I realized it after you raised this question. There are [plenty of styles](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted#Reference_guide) with which you can do whatever you want. It is also [possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584212/174620) to customize these styles if you are super enthu! See my edit for seeing some options you might find interesting.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help.

Comment: What would you write if you wanted all text to be black inside of the code-block (no syntax highlighting. We don't want `\usemintedstyle{perldoc}` or `\usemintedstyle{colorful}`

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon what about the example with `ffcode` package?

Comment: Also, it highly depends on your purpose. These packages provide a way to typeset code in simple LaTeX documents, but if you want to go slightly far with LaTeX and experience the new advancements, `l3doc` class is the one you need. It provides a lot of amazing features, but requires a different style of writing. Personally I find it absolutely worth it. If you want to see how it looks, you can have a look at the documentation of my packages, e.g., [`gfdl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gfdl).